# Facebook login causes endless redirect loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on asp.net mvc. I am trying to implement Facebook Integration for my MVC application. Here my i have chosen OAuth mechanism for facebook login. Here is my markup,

```
<a href="/Account/FacebookLogin">Login With Facebook</a>
```

and here is my action,

```
 public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
 {
            oAuthFacebook oauth = new oAuthFacebook();
            return new RedirectResult(oauth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
 }
```

And my callback url is `/Home/FBLogin`

```
public ActionResult FBLogin()
{
    oAuthFacebook oAuth = new oAuthFacebook();    
      if (Request["code"] == null)
      {
          //Redirect the user back to Facebook for authorization.
          return new RedirectResult(oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet());
      }
      else
      {
            oAuth.AccessTokenGet(Request["code"]);    
            if (oAuth.Token.Length > 0)
            {
               //Handle Accesstoken : oAuth.Token
            }
      }
      return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");                
 }
```

Here my problem is when i already login in Facebook site and then open my site and click on login with facebook button it works very fine.

But if I didn't login in facebook site and i want to freshly login into facebook via my mvc app. it causes facebook redirect loop that means it keep on calling my callback url so that i can't redirect to Dashboard action in my case and it stops me in the Facebook login page with reloading. I have cleared all cookies and try but it doesn't change. I am unable to find whether the mistake is i my side or facebook side.

**UPDATE:**
If I add an attribute `auth_type=reauthenticate` to solves my problem and is works fine. If i already logged in in facebook site it reauthenticate me. If i logged out in facebook site and try to login via my application it asks me the password about **2 times** One for normal login and another for re-authenticate login. Is there any way that i overcome this behavior? please guide me. Thanks you.

Comment: I think this is the same problem with this bug ticket (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/294349164040486).

Comment: I think I have same problem as you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522554/oauthwebsecurity-verifyauthentication-causes-multiple-requests-to-callback, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Please have a look on my update in question.

Comment: It's not much of a fix, but maybe you are on to something. For me it's not acceptable solution to force my users to login twice, that would be worse then registering them. The whole point of FB auth is to minimize filling out forms.